# Offset in function in disassembler output

Tags: debugging, disassembly, objdump

Cannot find *(or formulate a question to Google to find)* an answer on the simple *(or noob)* question.
I'm inspecting an application with `objdump -d` tool:

`. . . 
5212c0:  73 2e  jae    5212f0 <rfb::SMsgReaderV3::readSetDesktopSize()+0x130>
5213e8:  73 2e  jae    521418 <rfb::SMsgReaderV3::readSetDesktopSize()+0x258>
521462:  73 2c  jae    521490 <rfb::SMsgReaderV3::readSetDesktopSize()+0x2d0>
 . . .`

What does it mean the `+XXXX` offset in the output? How can I relate it to the source code, if possible? (Postprocessed with `c++filt`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the offset in bytes from the beginning of the function.

Here's an example from WinDbg, but it's the same everywhere:

This is the current call stack:

```
0:000> k L1
 # Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00 00000000`001afcb8 00000000`77b39ece USER32!NtUserGetMessage+0xa
```

This is how the function looks like:

```
0:000> uf USER32!NtUserGetMessage
USER32!NtUserGetMessage:
00000000`77b39e90 4c8bd1          mov     r10,rcx
00000000`77b39e93 b806100000      mov     eax,1006h
00000000`77b39e98 0f05            syscall
00000000`77b39e9a c3              ret
```

And this is what the current instruction is:

```
0:000> u USER32!NtUserGetMessage+a L1
USER32!NtUserGetMessage+0xa:
00000000`77b39e9a c3              ret
```

So, the offset `0x0A` is 10 bytes from the function start. 3 bytes for the first `mov`, 5 bytes for the second `mov` and 2 bytes for the `syscall`.

If you want to relate it to your code, it heavily depends on whether or not it was optimized.

If the offset is very high, you might not have enough symbols. E.g. with export symbols only you may see offsets like `+0x2AF4` and you can't tell anything about the real function any more.